# Should i continue working with hope of some project coming and a big raise or take the other oppurtunity that gives both of them?

Tags: salary, job-change

I am a software developer at a big firm , since the past couple of months there hasn't been any project in the technology i specialize . But this wasn't always the case , i was assigned to two different projects when i had entered this organization and i owe a lot to this company for improving my overall skills . Lately , there has been no projects at all and i have seen some few other developers of other technologies facing the same thing in my organization .

I did gave 3 interviews in the past week and got selected in all of them . There are still 3 months left for my bond to complete here (I don't have anything to lose if i break it too , as they just had my certificates from graduation which i received back last month) . The overall environment is pretty good in the organization , and everyone knows me around here quite well too as i am the sole developer in the technology i work in .

My question is , what should i do in such a situation . Should i wait for 3 months , collect my raise (Which i am not sure as there haven't been any projects lately but company policy entitles everyone to an yearly raise) and then leave or leave now and join another company which is offering the same salary which i would had got here after a raise .

PS - This is my first job change and i am looking for helpful answers that would help me in making the correct decision .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have decided to leave than you should leave now. No point in dragging this out. "Now" means: as soon as your current contract allows and soon as you can do professionally without doing harm or burning bridges.

It still may be worth exploring a future with your current employer. Have an open talk with your manager about what your goals and aspirations are and if there is any chance that you this could happen at your current gig. Since you have already something new lined up, there is very low risk in this and most managers will appreciate a chance to work the problem instead of just walking out.

Comment: I would certainly have a talk with your current employer. Definitely don't tell them you have another offer. If after the talk you are still considering to stay then give a counter offer to the other company that is a fair amount above what you expect to be making in 3 months. If they accept your counter offer then that might make your decision a whole lot more easy. If they don't, then you were probably going to stay where you are anyways. Nothing lost.

Comment: Thanks @Hilmar & Dunk . i have scheduled a meeting with my manager today . Lets see how it goes :)

Answer (score 1):

Hilmar's answer is correct, but I want to also point out that you don't owe anything to the company.  Yes, you learned skills working with them, but you did it in order to work on a project for them, which likely benefited them as much or more than learning the skills benefited you.  You should not feel like you have to give them extra consideration just because they trained you at first.  That said, if you like your current place it is definitely worth asking your manager when the next project may be, or asking about being moved to a department with more work.  Just keep in mind that the reason you are giving them extra consideration is because it benefits you (you are used to the place, won't have to move, etc), not because you owe them anything.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I'd say that if in doubt, stay where you are.

Whenever you start a new job, there's always a period of time where the company figures out just what you really now and how much you know and how you fit in the organization. It takes time for people to recognize your ability. And you say this is your first job, so presumably you are still learning and gaining experience. If you change jobs, you have to start all over, where you're again the unknown.

You don't want to get a reputation as someone who doesn't stay long at any one job. Years ago I was involved in hiring someone and we got one resume from someone who had one year at this job, six months at that job, nine months at another, a few weeks at another, etc. We had no way to know whether companies hired him and then figured out that he was incompetent or lazy and laid him off, or if he quickly got bored with each job and moved on. But either way, it was pretty obvious that if we hired him, within a year he'd be leaving. This was for a software development job, so it would surely take months for him to learn all the tools we used and get even a basic understanding of our company's systems, and then once we'd invested all that time in training, he'd be leaving. We threw the resume out. We didn't want to bother with such a person. As my boss at the time said, one job where a person leaves in a couple of months, you might say, oh, he took the job and then realized that it wasn't what he thought, he made a mistake. But a dozen in a row? No.

You say the company doesn't have any projects in your specialty. Is there an imminent danger that they will lay you off? If so, that's a good reason to look for another job. Better to look for a job at your leisure, when you can turn down offers that are undesirable for whatever reason, then to be in a position where you have to take whatever is available.

Maybe this is an opportunity to learn some new skills. Is whatever your "specialty" is something that you love so much that you don't want to get into something else? The more different skills you have, the more choices you have for future jobs. If you're in a technical field, specialties can become obsolete. I started out as a COBOL programmer. Not many jobs for that skill set any more. I've learned many new skills over the years to stay current.

Comment: Hi Jay , thanks for the detailed answer . No there isn't threats of layoff in here as it's a pretty much a very big company and i haven't seen anyone getting fired too . FYI , im a ROR developer and i have helped complete the company 2 projects in phonegap too . I believe in learning new technologies too :)